# how to show 1st row if 2nd table row is not found

Tags: php, mysql

how to show 1st row if 2nd table row is not found please see the example
thanks

```
$result1 = mysql_query("
SELECT a.user_name
     , a.date
     , a.checkin
     , o.checkout
  FROM attend a
  LEFT
  JOIN attendout o
    ON a.user_name = o.user_name 
   AND a.date = o.date
 WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-09' 
   AND o.user_name = 'salman';
");
```

now it is showing like this

```
username   date      checkin    checkout
salman  2015-06-01  11:31:34    17:23:47
salman  2015-06-02  11:19:23    17:15:15
salman  2015-06-03  11:48:22    18:16:27
salman  2015-06-06  11:39:26    16:56:13
salman  2015-06-07  11:24:59    17:36:01
```

and i want like this

```
   username   date      checkin    checkout
    salman  2015-06-01  11:31:34    17:23:47
    salman  2015-06-02  11:19:23    17:15:15
    salman  2015-06-03  11:48:22    18:16:27
    salman  2015-06-06  11:39:26    16:56:13
    salman  2015-06-07  11:24:59    17:36:01
    salman  2015-06-08  12:24:59
    salman  2015-06-09  10:24:59
```

because some time checkout row is null

Comment: This renders as an INNER JOIN. If you want an OUTER JOIN, move the last line before the WHERE line.

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition on the *second* table from the `WHERE` to the `ON`:

```
SELECT a.user_name, a.date, a.checkin, o.checkout
FROM attend a LEFT JOIN
     attendout o
     ON a.user_name = o.user_name AND
        a.date = o.date AND  o.user_name = 'salman'
WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-09' ;
```

When you put the condition in the `WHERE` clause you are turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, because the `NULL` values are filtered out.

Comment: i change it but this error is comming Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in view.php on line 181

Answer (score 0):

Add condition for checkout column:

```
SELECT attend.user_name,attend.date,attend.checkin, attendout.checkout
FROM attend 
left join  attendout on attend.user_name=attendout.user_name AND attend.date=attendout.date
WHERE attend.date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' 
AND '2015-06-09' 
AND attendout.user_name='salman'
AND attendout.checkout IS NOT NULL
```

or use != operator if value can be empty

Full code:
if you dont have any records, replacing LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN will work for you

```
$result1 = mysql_query("
SELECT a.user_name
     , a.date
     , a.checkin
     , o.checkout
  FROM attend a
  JOIN attendout o
    ON a.user_name = o.user_name 
   AND a.date = o.date
 WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-09' 
   AND o.user_name = 'salman';
");
```

Otherwise use:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("
SELECT a.user_name
     , a.date
     , a.checkin
     , o.checkout
  FROM attend a
  LEFT JOIN attendout o
    ON a.user_name = o.user_name 
   AND a.date = o.date
 WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-09' 
   AND o.user_name = 'salman'
   AND o.checkout != ''
   AND o.checkout IS NOT NULL;
");
```

Comment: try attendout.checkout != '' if field is empty

Comment: now this error is showing Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in view.php on line 182

Comment: SELECT attend.user_name,attend.date,attend.checkin, attendout.checkout ".
 "FROM attend join  attendout on attend.user_name=attendout.user_name AND attend.date=attendout.date ".
    "WHERE attend.date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' AND attendout.user_name='$c'  AND attendout.checkout !=

Comment: look on my answer, updated, use it and tell my if its works

Comment: i replace both code but result is same i don't understand what is the problem

Comment: insert full code on some fiddle site and show to us